# KnockOutJS trigger parent function on child subscribe

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am currently trying to learn KnockOutJS. I thought it would be a great idea to create a simple task-list application.
I do not want to write a long text here, let's dive into my problem. I appreciate all kind of help - I am new to KnockOutJS tho!

The tasks are declared as followed:

```
var Task = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.status = ko.observable(data.status);
    self.priority = ko.observable(data.priority);
}
```

And the view model looks like this

```
var TaskListViewModel = function() {
var self = this;

self.currentTask = ko.observable();
self.currentTask(new Task({ name: "", status: false, priority: new Priority({ name: "", value: 0 }) }));

self.tasksArr = ko.observableArray();

self.tasks = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.tasksArr.slice().sort(self.sortTasks);
}, self);

self.sortTasks = function (l, r) {
    if (l.status() != r.status()) {
        if (l.status()) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }

    return (l.priority().value > r.priority().value) ? 1 : -1;
};

self.priorities = [
    new Priority({ name: "Low", value: 3 }),
    new Priority({ name: "Medium", value: 2 }),
    new Priority({ name: "High", value: 1 })
];

// Adds a task to the list
// also saves updated task list to localstorage
self.addTask = function () {
    self.tasksArr.push(new Task({ name: self.currentTask().name(), status: false, priority: self.currentTask().priority() }));
    self.localStorageSave();

    self.currentTask().name("");
};

// Removes a task to a list
// also saves updated task list to localstorage
self.removeTask = function (task) {
    self.tasksArr.remove(task);
    self.localStorageSave();
};

// Simple test function to check if event is fired.
self.testFunction = function (task) {
    console.log("Test function called");
};

// Saves all tasks to localStorage
self.localStorageSave = function () {
    localStorage.setItem("romaTasks", ko.toJSON(self.tasksArr));
};

// loads saved data from localstorage and parses them correctly.
self.localStorageLoad = function () {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("romaTasks"));
    if (parsed != null) {
        var tTask = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
            tTask = new Task({
                name: parsed[i].name,
                status: parsed[i].status,
                priority: new Priority({
                    name: parsed[i].priority.name,
                    value: parsed[i].priority.value
                })
            });
            self.tasksArr.push(tTask);
        }
    }
};
self.localStorageLoad();
}
```

What I want to do in my html is pretty simple.
All tasks I have added are saved to localStorage. The save function is, as you can see, called each time an element has been added & removed. But I also want to save as soon as the status of each task has been changed, but it is not possible to use subscribe here, such as

```
self.status.subscribe(function() {});
```

because I cannot access self.tasksArr from the Task class.

Any idea? Is it possible to make the self.tasksArr public somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here comes RP Niemeyer!

Comment: Why not subscribe to it in your `addTask()` method? Create the Task, then subscribe to `status`. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe in the handler, `this` would point to your `ko.observable()` for `status`.

Comment: hm.. subscribe to addTask method? Not quite sure what that would like to. do you mean when creating the task:

var status = ko.observable(false);
status.subscribe(function() {
// do something
});

listOfTasks.push(new Task({status:status}));

something like this? or how did you mean?

Comment: No, subscribe to `Task.status` inside the `addTask` function (when you're creating the `Task`). Along the lines of `task=new Task(...); task.status.subscribe(function(newValue) {...})`

Comment: This solved it! Thanks so much! Didn't know this was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.addTask = function () {
  var myTask = new Task({ name: self.currentTask().name(), status: false, priority: self.currentTask().priority() })
  myTask.status.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    self.localStorageSave();
  });
  self.tasksArr.push(myTask);
  self.localStorageSave();
  self.currentTask().name("");
};
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Exactly the same thing that @Pete described in his last comment. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that? Oh wait, I did!